# Package or namespace load failed for ‘RxODE’ .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'RxODE',

Tags: namespaces, invalid-argument

I am trying to create a model simulation using RxODE, this R-code was successful previously on a colleague's computer. R was just reinstalled on the computer I am currently using (version 3.6.2). I continue to get this error...

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RxODE’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'RxODE', details:
  call: !.rxWinRtoolsPath(retry = NA)
  error: invalid argument type

I have tried .libPaths(.libPaths()[2]), reinstalling all my packages, and to install RxODE with dependencies=TRUE.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/cran/RxODE/issues/1#issuecomment-320900446

I had the same problem like you and could solve it with the description given in the link.

Or in other words, just try to run this code:

```
    path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
    path <- c("C:\Rtools\bin", "C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin", path)
    path <- paste(path,collapse=";")
    Sys.setenv(PATH=path)
    Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

Best wishes