# Difficulty loading package RxODE

Tags: r

I am having issues loading RxODE package:

**Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RxODE’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'RxODE', details:
  call: !.rxWinRtoolsPath(retry = NA)
  error: invalid argument type**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994246/package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-rxode-onattach-failed-in-attachnamespace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package or namespace load failed for ‘RxODE’ .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'RxODE',](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994246/package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-rxode-onattach-failed-in-attachnamespace)